# Spring Security javaConfig logon post not resolving

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

It works using XML config, but JavaConfig confounds. I have:

- gen controller is serving logon page so I can list clients at logon
- custom `UserDetailsServiceImpl` so I can auth against DB

The problem is that posting the logon form gets:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Breakpoint inside `securityConfig` at startup shows it loaded and it seems `http.configurers` are set however `loginProcessingUrl` does not seem to be catching the logon form post.

```java
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/conv/*" };
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.antMatcher("/conv/u/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
        http.antMatcher("/conv/a/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/conv/common/logon");
        http.formLogin().usernameParameter("userName");
        http.formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/conv/", true);
        http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/conv/common/logon");
        http.formLogin().failureUrl("/conv/common/logon?error=true");

        http.logout().logoutUrl("/conv/common/logout");
        http.logout().invalidateHttpSession(true);
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/conv/common/message?message='logged out'").deleteCookies("conv+[35randomChars], JSESSIONID").permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/common/**")
        .antMatchers("/favicon.ico");
    }


    @Bean
    public SaltSource saltSource() {
        ReflectionSaltSource rss = new ReflectionSaltSource();
        rss.setUserPropertyToUse("xyz");
        return rss;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

}


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/common/logon")
public ModelAndView logonHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Client> clients = clientManager.searchClients("", null, null, null);
    ...
    return new ModelAndView("common/logon", "clients", clients);
}
```

```html
<form:form name="logonForm" action="/conv/common/logon" method="post" target="_top" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="userLogon" required="required" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus"/>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form:form>
```

[image]

Comment: add: <input type="hidden"
name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
value="${_csrf.token}"/> to your jsp form and/or show your controller

Comment: yes, i have that hidden field (added it above). Controller handling GET request for logon also added for clarity. Its the POST that does not seemed mapped. I even tried forrm action="j_spring_security_check" to no avail. Breakpoint at security config at startup screensnap added above

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<form:form name="logonForm" action="/conv/common/logon" method="post" target="_top" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="userLogon" required="required" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus"/>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form:form>
```

to this (just removed method="post" and csrf, these are automatically inserted by spring:form)

```
<form:form name="logonForm" action="/conv/common/logon" target="_top" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="userLogon" required="required" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus"/>
</form:form>
```

In your Controller, change this

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/common/logon")
```

to this (just removed method=RequestMethod.GET)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/common/logon")
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out

first fix:

public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {..}
is not in any online examples. 
Didn't even know that was required.
Reading new spring.io 4.0 docs gave me the answer.

i added:

```
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
```

}

and now the settings in SecurityConfiguration are read

---

second fix:

"http" and "and()" in security config were never explained in the many online examples.

it took a complete read of the 4+ security docs from spring.io to understand it

confusing that "http" is in: configure(HttpSecurity http), but "represents" the "http" xml tag in the old xml config file.

never knew ".and()" represents a closing xml tag.

why no final ".and()" on last item?

why do some settings like .csrf().disable() not need be closed with .and()?

.and() appears only necc. to close parent, not child xml tags